# how to prevent a save button from calling javascript validation when the same is used for update functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using a button which is used for both saving and updating data.I want to call the javascript validation function when it is used to save and not when it is used to update data.How can i do this?

Comment: Please provide some code you wrote

Comment: Are you changing the Button text from "Save" to "Update" also, or text will always be "Save" only. How are you differentiating when to save and when to update? Can you provide your code for better understanding?

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

a button that can perform save and update? in code behind? you may call your script when ur button perform save function

this is something like this

```
//save function - with javascript validation
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
GetType(), 
"MyKey", 
"Myfunction();", 
true);
//update function
without javascript validation
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really specified how your validation works; however, if you are using jQuery Validate, you can prevent validation on a "save for later" type button simply by adding  `class="cancel"` to your input tag.